# Populate dataframe for specific rows using values in R

Tags: r

For a sample dataframe:

```
country = c("uk", "fr", "it") 
N = c(100, 80, 95)
df <- data.frame(country, N)
```

I wish to populate two extra columns (say 'a_col' and 'b_col') in my 'df' dataframe with values calculated from a previous command.  For simplicity, values for the UK to populate the two columns (first row) mentioned above would be:

```
a <- 5.5
b <- 3.6
```

How would I add these values to the dataframe in the right row? (i.e. for the UK only, not the other countries).  If it could be wrapped up in a function, I guess that would be the easiest - could I use 'sapply'?

Comment: You can use `cbind(df, a_col=a, b_col=b)` or `transform` or `data.frame` or `within` etc.

Comment: `df$new_column <- some_value`?

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  I know how to add the same value for entire column, but not specifying the value with reference to a row in another column - i.e. the a and b values would just refer to the UK - I would then calculate another a and b with reference to values for 'FR' and then add these individually to the dataframe also - how would I do that?

Comment: Thanks @nrussell - but I wanted to instead add these values just for the UK row (sorry if I wasn't clear... I have edited my answer).  I will then have different values for the other countries.

Comment: You could use `ifelse` i.e. `ifelse(df$country=='uk', a, NA)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  If I didn't want to add the else (since I will be repeating the same process with lots of countries), why doesn't df$a_col <- if(df$country=='uk', a) work or this df$a_col <- if(df$country=='uk') {a} ?

Comment: It is because `if` is not vectorized.  If the logical index is just a single value, it should work.

Comment: Thanks @akrun, but I still don't understand.  In the above example, the logical index does refer to a single value (uk) but I get the warning message Error: unexpected ',' in "df$a_col <- if(df$country=='uk',"  How can I get this to work?

Comment: @KT_1 If you look a the `df$country=='uk'` it is a vector of length >1.  THe `if/else` works when the length is 1.

Comment: Ok, I understand that.  But (1) why does ifelse work in these circumstances? df$a_col <- ifelse(df$country=='uk', a, NA) ... and (2)how would I get my if command to reference just the UK, therefore of length one?